# Bigcommerce Stencil Common Product Card Model has_options attribute not working

Tags: bigcommerce

According to the documentation, there is a `has_options` attribute on the [Common Product Card Model](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/product-resources#Stencil-ProdCardObj-ref) that should return a boolean showing whether or not the product has options.

However, this value is returning `false` for all of my products, even though they have options. For example, if I access the homepage in debug mode via this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/?debug=context
```

One of the products under the featured products section is:

```
{
    "id": 114,
    "name": "Product Name",
    "url": "http://www.example.com/product-url",
    "brand": null,
    "rating": 5,
    "availability": "Usually ships the next business day",
    "summary": "Product summary goes here",
    "image": {
        "data": "https://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/server2100/abcdef/images/stencil/{:size}/products/114/8086/product_image.jpg?c=2",
        "alt": ""
    },
    "date_added": "January 6, 2014",
    "qty_in_cart": 0,
    "pre_order": false,
    "has_options": false,
    "show_cart_action": false,
    "add_to_wishlist_url": "/wishlist.php?action=add&product_id=114",
    "price": {
    "without_tax": {
        "formatted": "$19.99",
        "value": 19.99
    },
    "rrp_without_tax": {
        "formatted": "$24.99",
        "value": 24.99
    },
    "saved": {
        "formatted": "$5.00",
        "value": 5
    },
    "tax_label": "Tax"
    }
}
```

As you can see `has_options` is `false`. However, this product does have options. Via the control panel, I can see that it has a color swatch option. I can also see this by navigating to the products page in debug mode at `http://localhost:3000/product-url?debug=context`. As you can see, part of the output contains the options information for that product:

```
"options": [
    {
        "id": 498,
        "type": "Configurable_PickList_Swatch",
        "display_name": "Color",
        "required": true,
        "condition": true,
        "values": [
            {
                "label": "Powder Coat Black",
                "id": 390,
                "data": [
                    "000000"
                ],
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "label": "Anodized Aluminum",
                "id": 391,
                "data": [
                    "D9D9D9"
                ],
                "selected": false
            }
        ],
        "partial": "swatch"
    }
],
```

As you can see, the product does in fact have options, yet the Common Product Card Model for this product shows `has_options` as `false`.

Is there some other setting that is effecting the output of `has_options`? Why would it be showing `false` for a product that has options?

Comment: Can you post a pastebin or something with the file content?

Comment: Which file? This is the file that I'm trying to use the `has_options` attribute in: http://pastebin.com/60wSPhdk but the output shown in the question is not from a file. It's just from loading the site in [debug mode](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/testingdebugging-themes) in order to view the context. You can see it's showing `has_options` is `false` even for a product that does in fact have options.

Answer (score 0):

`has_options` is used to denote something is purchasable (true) or not (false). This is misleading and documentation will be revised to reflect this.

Comment: Are you sure about that? That still doesn't make sense since the products I was checking are purchasable, so should have returned `true`. When I submitted this issue to support it was escalated and eventually identified as a bug. They gave me ticket number MERC-537.

Comment: Since I spoke to one of the engineers that worked on Stencil, I am reasonably sure :) we can create a ticket to revise behavior when we identify it is undesirable.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. But, in this case, I still think there is a bug, because every product is returning false even if it is purchasable. What is causing that?

Comment: It seems like the `show_cart_action` attribute is the one that should denote whether or not something is purchasable. This attribute is exhibiting the same issue as `has_options`. It's always `false`.

Comment: `show_cart_action`
indicates whether or not the store has enabled the add to cart link in
small product boxes and that the product is available for purchase. If that
value is true, then the `has_options` attribute indicates whether or not
the product has options.

Comment: Ha, thanks. This is word for word what I explained to your support rep this morning via email, so I'm assuming this means she agreed with my comments. Thank you again for looking into this.