# Bigcommerce Stencil use handlebars helper in css to set background image

Tags: bigcommerce

Is there any way to reference a cdn image location from a CSS file in order to set a background image? For example, in a component file I can reference an image file using:

```
{{cdn 'img/my-image.jpg'}}
```

If I want to use that image as a background image in css, I need to set it in the stylesheet. For example:

```
.element {
    background-image: url({{cdn 'img/my-image.jpg'}});
}
```

Is this possible, or do I need to set the background image inline in the html?

I see that there is a custom `stencilString` method, but I don't know how this would work in my situation, since I wouldn't want to hardcode the entire URL of the image on the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Currently with Stencil, there is not a way to reference it with a variable. This is available with blueprint.

Comment: Thanks, can someone please help me out with this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36000933/736864

Answer (score 0):

You could always set it using an inline style:

```
<div class="element" style="url( {{getImage image 'gallery' (cdn 'img/my-image.jpg') }}">
```

'gallery refers to the size of image to get. See {{getImage}} helper doc [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/custom-handlebars-helpers)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the question.